# Multiple radio button groups who send data in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried the following:

```
<%= form_for .... do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "test1" %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'value[]', "1" %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'value[]', "2" %>
    <%= f.label "test2" %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "value[]", "1" %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "value[]", "2" %>
    <%= f.submit "test_send" %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller i then have an array.

**The problem now is** that i can only select one of this four, but i want select them after group. With `text_fields` it works fine but with radio buttons it doesn't work.

Then i tried something like:

```
<%= form_for .... do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "test1" %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'value[]', "1", :id => "btn-grp-1"  %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'value[]', "2", :id => "btn-grp-2"  %>
    <%= f.label "test2" %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "value[]", "1", :id => "btn-grp-3"  %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "value[]", "2", :id => "btn-grp-4"  %>
    <%= f.submit "test_send" %>
<% end %>
```

to have unique id's but still the same problem.
What i need is to have a unique name for every group like:

```
<%= form_for .... do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "test1" %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'value[1]', "1", :id => "btn-grp-1"  %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'value[1]', "2", :id => "btn-grp-2"  %>
    <%= f.label "test2" %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "value[2]", "1", :id => "btn-grp-3"  %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "value[2]", "2", :id => "btn-grp-4"  %>
    <%= f.submit "test_send" %>
<% end %>
```

But how can i get the params now?

**My controller contains ony code for test what is send:**

```
...
def create

    flash[:success] = valueset_params[:value]
    redirect_to root_path
end


private

def valueset_params
  params.permit({value: []})
end
...
```

Hope you understand what i mean. (I have to change the name of the radio buttons and i still want receive the full array in my controller).

Just ask if you don't.

Thanks for any solution propose.

---

**Edit** Another question:

I have something like `@topics` where i have multiple topics inside.
Now i want loop them (i know how this works) and write variable values inside the []

```
<%= form_for .... do |f| %>
  <%= f.label 'test1' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'value[@topic1.id]', '1' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'value[@topic1.id]', '2' %>
  <%= f.label 'test2' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'value[@topic2.id]', '1' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'value[@topic2.id]', '2' %>
  <%= f.submit 'test_send' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this and let me know what happens:

```
<%= form_for .... do |f| %>
  <%= f.label 'test1' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'value[group_one]', '1' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'value[group_one]', '2' %>
  <%= f.label 'test2' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'value[group_two]', '1' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'value[group_two]', '2' %>
  <%= f.submit 'test_send' %>
<% end %>
```

You should be able to get your data in the controller with `params[:value]` and then `params[:value][:group_one]` and `params[:value][:group_two]`.

Comment: Nice this works to me.
I'll update my question above because i have another question.
Maybe you can help me again. :)

Comment: For your 2nd question, just use `"value[#{topic.id}]"` with a surrounding loop going `@topics.each do |topic| ... end`

Comment: Thank you! I tried around so long. Amazing Answers!