# Rails 4 : Updating attribute with an array driven by radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, radio-button

This question is very similar to: [Multiple radio button groups who send data in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876051/multiple-radio-button-groups-who-send-data-in-an-array) but I can't seem to make the leap to my use case.

I'm modeling a game which has always has 8 roles (:strategy_cards) which I want to pass as an array. Each of these roles could be one of several values.

@games.select_strategy_cards passes back my hash :

```
{"Initiative" => 1, "Diplomacy" => 2, "Political" => 3, "Logistics" => 4, "Trade" => 5, "Warfare" => 6, "Technology" => 7,"Imperial" => 8, "Leadership" => 1,"Diplomacy II" => 2,"Assembly" => 3,"Production" => 4,"Trade II" => 5,"Warfare II" => 6,"Technology II" => 7,"Bureaucracy" => 8,"Imperial II" =>8, "Trade III" => 5,"Political II" => 3,"Assembly II" => 3}
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
  <% i=[*1..8].each do |v| %>
    <div>
      <h2><%= v %></h2>

      <% @game.select_strategy_cards.each do |key, value| %>
         <% if value == v %>
            <%= f.label key %>
            <%= radio_button_tag "game[strategy_cards][#{value}]", key  %>
         <% end %>
     <% end %>

    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Which generates divs marked 1-8 and creates the radio buttons as desired. I think that my problem is with "game[strategy_cards][#{value}]"

But I cannot, for the life of me, figure it out.

UPDATE

Changed

to

As per Ryan's suggestion. The hash looks to be getting created fine (although an array would be better):

```
Started PATCH "/games/98/game_steps/strategy_cards" for ::1 at 2015-04-17 19:53:26 -0700
Processing by GameStepsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4eQPqXt9tMo/ZJ4mvgT8JJ4QmLVSqqZoayIv1Zt/2c7yFmikOIgGJH2Vc0vdt3UOBlF7H0jH8mDRaTs3VFTgDg==", "game"=>{"strategy_cards"=>{"1"=>"Leadership", "2"=>"Diplomacy II", "3"=>"Assembly II", "4"=>"Production", "5"=>"Trade III", "6"=>"Warfare II", "7"=>"Technology II", "8"=>"Imperial II"}}, "commit"=>"Update Game", "game_id"=>"98", "id"=>"strategy_cards"}
  [1m[36mGame Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 98]]
Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "games" SET "strategy_cards" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "games"."id" = ?[0m  [["strategy_cards", "{}"], ["updated_at", "2015-04-18 02:53:26.708415"], ["id", 98]]
  [1m[35m (1.2ms)[0m  commit transaction
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/games/98/game_steps/wicked_finish
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

But it is not updating :strategy_cards. Here is my permit:

```
def game_params
  params.require(:game).permit(:shattered_empire, :shards_of_the_throne, :number_of_players, {:rules => []}, {:strategy_cards => []}, :players, {:races => []})
end
```

UPDATE 2

So the issue appears to be:

Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Changing my permit to permit! does allow the hash to pass through but this doesn't seem optimal.

UPDATE 3

Kind of gross but

```
def game_params
  params.require(:game).permit(:shattered_empire, :shards_of_the_throne, :number_of_players, {:rules => []}, {:strategy_cards => [:"1",:"2",:"3",:"4",:"5",:"6",:"7",:"8"]},:players, {:races => []})
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you should change

```
<%= radio_button_tag "game[strategy_cards][#{value}]", key  %>
```

to:

```
<%= radio_button_tag "game[strategy_cards][#{v}]", key  %>
```

That way, they are listed as `1..8` instead of the values of your "roles".

Comment: That one thing that I tried. Since value == v it didn't make any difference. I think I really want v-1 so I'm properly indexing the array.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are the params not submitting correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's about it.  From the logger it looks like things are getting created correctly. Will post in update. It creates a hash but the attribute is not getting updated. Will also post permit.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm beginning to understand what is going on. Can you also post the raw `params` that are sent to the server?

Comment: It's up in UPDATE. The issue is, that the code as written treats the strategy cards as another hash. It passes (for instance) "8"=>"Imperial II" in the params. So :8 is now a param. Would be nice to have it pass to an array as intended but it is working atm.