# How radio_button can return value in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

For example a have collection radio buttons:

```
= f.collection_radio_buttons :types, @languages, :itself, :itself, checked: ['java'],
    include_hidden: false, multiple: true do |b|
      .form-check-input
        = b.radio_button  
        = b.label
```

If i select radio_button, params return 'java'. But i need return array. For example ['java'].

Question:

Is it possible return radio_buton with value array?

Comment: Please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876051/multiple-radio-button-groups-who-send-data-in-an-array . Or you can also follow this article https://makandracards.com/alexander-m/40461-a-hidden-field-on-collection-radio-buttons

Comment: thank you. Now my params return params['user']['lang'] is 'java', but how return ['java']?

Comment: form.collection_radio_buttons :language, [['java'],['ruby'],['cobol']], :first, :first, include_hidden: false . However, it will generate 3 radio buttons. I suggest easy way, just post normal radio buttion with value: 'java,ruby,cobol' and then in controller, using split method to convert it to array. posting string is faster than array

Comment: Hi Stefan. It would help us figure out how to do this if you explain to us why you need this? Why is `'java'` not ok but `['java']` is what you want?

Comment: becose in my userscontroler `params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, languages: [])` and i need set params languages like array.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: i am using  rails 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution:

```
.form-check
    %label
      = t('auth.users.form.roles_label')
    = f.collection_radio_buttons :languages, @languages, :itself, :itself, { checked: ['java'], include_hidden: false }, { multiple: true } do |b|
      .form-check-input
        = b.radio_button  
        = b.label
```

Comment: Can you also post the html that produces?  Where did you find documentation on what goes in the `options` hash, i.e. the first of the two hash arguments?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible return radio_buton with value array?

Yes.  Here is the type of html you need:

```
<form method="post" action="/dave" name="languages">
  <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
  <div><input type="radio" name="languages[]" value="java" />Java</div>
  <div><input type="radio" name="languages[]" value="ruby" />Ruby</div>
  <div><input type="radio" name="languages[]" value="python" />Python</div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

This is what I see in params:

```
Parameters: {
"authenticity_token"=>"<omitted>", 
"languages"=>["java"], 
"submit"=>"Submit"
}
```

Comment: this is hard way, becose in my situation input has `name="user[languages]"` and i dont want use javascript for changing attribute of name. I have found solution. see my answer.